# Manipulate physical function buttons (windows)

Tags: vb.net, powershell, key-bindings

Is it possible to change function for certain function keys with either PowerShell or VB.NET? 
I got a tiny keyboard, with media-buttons, and tired of deactivating these in BIOS from time to time.

Not really sure where to start here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For PowerShell is `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler` an option?

Goal:

```
Get-key f1
Set-value fn+f1
```

Comment: This can be specific to the keyboard driver and is generally not available to user code. It would help to know the keyboard manufacturer and model number, and computer BIOS version. Is it attached to your laptop? Otherwise I don't know how your computer BIOS would change settings on a plugged-in keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell isn't really the best keyboard remapping tool. It *can* be done, but I would look at other tools like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) that are designed to use keyboard hooks to intercept keystrokes and can remap them see: [Remapping Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)

An example remapping file is:

ex.ahk

```
a::b
```

Save it, run the AutoHotKey compiler to make an .`exe`, then set up a Scheduled Task to run on login.